# iOS offline distribution of provisioning certificates

Tags: ios, xcode7, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am using xcode 7 and it allows for testing on real devices without enrolling in apple developer program.
We are a team of 5 members and i have already downloaded the certificates and was able to test on real devices but now we need certificates on other systems too. Is there a way to export same certificates offline or there is a need of internet everytime.

Answer (score 0):

No need for internet for getting certificates.

Here are the steps to export certificates from your system:

1. Open Keychain Access.
2. Tap on Certificates.
3. Right Click on Selected Certificate which you want to Use in another System.
4. Tap on Export certificates.

Comment: Thanks @Mihir Will the same apple id be used as team name for other systems?

Comment: Yes. first add your developer account in other system.

Comment: first add your app id in xCode-> preference.

Comment: I want to use free provisioning certificates without developer account. @Mihir

Comment: I think it is not possible. Because you must have developer account and also a valid provisioning certificates also verify that your iPhone/iPad's UDID register in developer account->device. Run your code in simulator. In simulator there is no need to use any provisioning certificates.

Comment: @kitty are you getting or not?

Comment: xcode 7 allows free development provisioning profile that makes testing possible on real devices without enrolling in developer program. link (https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/Articles/xcode_7_0.html)